# ERROR: Gradle 'android_10' project refresh failed

Tags: ros, ubuntu, ubuntu-trusty, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Android

```
Error:Unsupported method: BaseConfig.getApplicationIdSuffix().
The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model.
```

I am trying to use ROSJava in Android Studio 3.0.1 but following the installation instructions given [here](http://wiki.ros.org/android/Tutorials/indigo/Installation%20-%20ROS%20Development%20Environment) leads to this error in Android Studio. Please advise.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278173/error:-gradle-%27android_10%27-project-refresh-failed/) by [akshayk07](https://answers.ros.org/users/32988/akshayk07/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2017-12-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-25**:
A question with only an error message isn't a question.

**Comment by [akshayk07](https://answers.ros.org/users/32988/akshayk07/) on 2017-12-26**:
I have updated the question. Sorry for the incomplete question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like you accepted to change the Gradle version when Android Studio prompted if you wanted to do so.

Android Studio will find that there's a new Gradle version when you open a project, and a popup will appear to change it. Don't do it; newer Gradle versions may be incompatible. Just keep using the Gradle wrapper as it is in the projects; this doesn't have to do with Android Studio versions (I'm using 3.x.x and it works).

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2018-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1